# 'java.net.SocketException: Socket closed' exception in the jenkins jobs execution

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, socket-timeout-exception, jenkins-kubernetes

we are using Kubernetes plugin to spin up the slaves to build the projects.
We have a jenkins jobs that is scheduled to run on the kubernetes through jenkins k8 plugin. This job has all the shell script in various stages.
Jenkins master is on a Linux machine that connects with the slave pods via JNLP protocal. 
We are facing this intermittent issue in the jobs that fails the execution with of java.net.SocketException: Socket closed.

How can i increase the socket timeout? Where do i find this settings?
How can i fix this?

Attaching the below logs:

================================

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:204)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
Caused: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:354)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:226)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:119)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:112)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:411)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:372)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:337)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:318)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:827)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:220)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:164)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.waitUntilCondition(BaseOperation.java:1030)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.waitUntilExists(BaseOperation.java:1014)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.HasMetadataOperation.waitUntilReady(HasMetadataOperation.java:209)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.HasMetadataOperation.waitUntilReady(HasMetadataOperation.java:36)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.waitUntilPodContainersAreReady(ContainerExecDecorator.java:460)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.doLaunch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:275)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.launch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:269)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:194)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor825.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [apttus-ui-builder-v2-grntk-jrlzw]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:231)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:164)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.waitUntilCondition(BaseOperation.java:1030)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.waitUntilExists(BaseOperation.java:1014)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.HasMetadataOperation.waitUntilReady(HasMetadataOperation.java:209)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.HasMetadataOperation.waitUntilReady(HasMetadataOperation.java:36)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.waitUntilPodContainersAreReady(ContainerExecDecorator.java:460)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.doLaunch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:275)
    at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1.launch(ContainerExecDecorator.java:269)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:194)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor825.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at UIPipeline.createNpmPackage(UIPipeline.groovy:636)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:84)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor345.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:107)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor345.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:87)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor345.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

================================

Comment: did you try to check the server overhead when the error happen?

Comment: I did, and it does increase the load. I have scaled out to a good node count. I am observing the result.